# What is a person who studied B.Sc./M.Sc./Ph.D. in computer science called?

Tags: word-usage

A dentist is a person who studied dentistry.

A civil engineer is a person who studied civil engineering.

What is a person who studied B.Sc./M.Sc./Ph.D. in computer science called?

Comment: Computer scientist, software engineer..........the list could get very long depending on the speciality.

Comment: "Computer geek" comes to mind!

Comment: @BruceMurray Do you call a person who studies B.Sc. in computer science, a computer scientist?

Comment: As long as he/she is enrolled, he/she is gonna be a student! I mean all of them ...

Comment: A dentist is someone who has studied dentistry, and now practices dentistry professionally. A computer scientist is someone who is employed in computer science.

Comment: @Abdulkadar.  No, I'm with Bill on this and would also call him a computer geek (laughs, applause), but the person in question might call himself computer scientist.  At least that is what he may put on his C.V.

Comment: I apologies for my typo, I have just edited the question.

Comment: @Abdulkadar. Computer scientist is the most appropriate in a general sense, if you don't know of any speciality.

Comment: If we call a person who studied B.Sc. in computer science a computer **scientist** even if he did not contribute to any research, will not it be overkill?

Comment: A computer scientist is someone who has acquired the knowledge of computer science and might work in that capacity.  Sometimes they have higher education qualifications and academic degrees in that field.

Comment: You can rightfully call them **Doctor**. Note that (in UK) many medical doctors (surgeons) are actually called **Mr**.

Comment: Aside: a dentist (and many other professionals) isn't a person who *studied* dentistry, but one who holds recognised qualifications to practice dentistry. At least, in UK.

Comment: How do they get those qualifications?

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm quite sure I want anyone going in my mouth with pliers, drills, etc, to have studied dentistry right up to qualification stage, and to have gained such a qualification.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that was the topic of your previous comment too. How could an accredited dentist not have studied dentistry? My comment was intended to point out that "someone who studied X" isn't sufficient. I studied biology at school, but I am not a biologist. A student who was sent down in year 1 isn't a dentist. Please move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A computer scientist".

This is assuming that we are talking of the person *as* a person who has a BSc in computer science.  That person could also have other roles in their life:  they might be a teacher, a football player and a beer drinker at other times.

But you could say

> If you want to discuss algorithms, you should talk to Jack.  He's a computer scientist.  He did a computer science degree at the University of York. Even though he's now teaching high school maths.

I would also be quite happy to call the undergraduate students "computer scientists" too.  This is really no different from calling somebody with an engineering degree, an "engineer", though they may well also have other roles (like teacher etc)